# Visual Studio Designer message

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

When try to open in design mode a form (VB.NET), in which I have a custom UserControl, I see the message from Visual Studio:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The control MyNamespace.MyUserControl has thrown an unhandled exception 
in the designer and has been disabled.  

Exception:
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'SplitterPanel'.

Stack trace:
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

And the form is not displayed in designer. What to do?

Answer (score 4):

Load up the project with Debug mode, and put a breakpoint on the `InitializeComponent()` function for your user control. You might have some bug in there that is disposing of an object named `SplitterPanel` and then trying to access it afterward. This initialization is run when Visual Studio is trying to render the control, leading to the error that you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you, Yaakov. I put a breackpoint on the InitializeComponent, but in design mode I don't stop on it... the MYUserControl itself is displaying good in the Designer. But it does not leave the form in witch is hosted to be displayed.

Comment: I have in the UserControl a SplitContainer, but any element named SplitterPanel...

Comment: ) related: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540882/the-control-control-has-thrown-an-unhandled-exception-in-the-designer-and-has-been-disabled

Comment: Do a Search [In Entire Solution] for "SplitterPanel"

Answer (score 3):

Remove the attribute

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
```

From InitializeComponent() inside the designer. This will allow you to step through the designer. To figure out exactly where the exception is thrown, you can also break when a CLR exception is thrown by

Debug menu >>> Exceptions >>> check the box "Common Language Runtime Exceptions", "Thrown"

With these two steps, you should be able to break where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You have to look in the designer of your form, for the call of `Dispose` method in `InitializeComponent` method. Something like this would written:

```
Me.SplitterPanel.Dispose()
```

Because of this call object destroy in the designer. So its no longer exists to display and make use of it.

Removal of this line will resolve the issue.